# Create modeless child form in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a desktop application (Main Form) which uploads data in order to perform some basic calculations.

I would like to include a Box popping up once the user has uploaded his file (e.g. “Upload has been completed”). This Box should have 2 characteristics:

1. It should be modeless, no input is needed, it is merely an
   information box
2. It should disappear automatically (based on a timer).

I have already found a solution for the second point, however I still have to create the form I would like to pop up. As I do not want it to have buttons, MessageBox is not a good fit.

I know that I can create a modeless form as follows:

```
 Public class test
 {
 Form f = new Form();
 f.show()
 }
```

Starting from that, how can I insert a string text and a string caption much similar to the messageBox style?

thanks

Comment: Define your own form class, add two properties for Title and Message. Set them to your text before calling Show();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can give you an idea how to start

```
public class MyDialog: Form
{
    public MyDialog(string prompt, int timeout)
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        rtb.Font = new Font("Times new Roman", 14f, FontStyle.Bold);
        rtb.Text = prompt;
        this.Controls.Add(rtb);

        var _Timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Interval = timeout
        };
        _Timer.Tick += (s, e) => this.Close();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

All you need to do is creating this form like below

```
var f = new MyDialog("It works", 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working quite nicely for me. I will mark it as answer! One last question out of curiosity, is it possible to actually omit/mute the typer in the richtextbox?

Comment: Do you mean setting *ReadOnly* ?

Comment: I have already set it to ReadOnly, however the typer still appears (Although you can no longer modify the RichTextBox content). It is just a matter of aesthetics and I am wondering whether it is somehow possible to hide the typer?

Comment: @DavidRaths you can use a `Label` instead of RTB.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

First, you can create a form, something like the following, which would be your message box equivalent.

[image]

Then you can change that new `Form2` constructor like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string title, string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = title;
        label1.Text = message;
    }
}
```

`this.Text` is your title and then by using `label1.Text`, set the label text.

Then, when you're launching the new form, do like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2("header","message");
    f2.Show();
}
```

And this is what you'll get:

[image]